# Help to get 100% test coverage for apex class requiring to populate only one of the two custom fields

Tags: apex, unit-test

Here is my apex class with validation rule to populate one of the two custom fields, and not allowing to populate both custom fields at the same time:

```
public with sharing class FieldnotEmptycontrl {
    public static void fieldNotEmpty(List<Property__c> prop){
        for(Property__c property: prop){
            //if both fields are empty the error message shows up
            if(property.Business__c == null && property.Contact__c == null) {

                property.Business__c.addError('You must enter a value!');
                property.Contact__c.addError('You must enter a value!');
            }
                //if both fields are not empty the error message shows up
            if(property.Business__c != null && property.Contact__c != null){

                 property.Business__c.addError('Cannot use two fields at the same time. Please choose only one field Business or Contact');
                 property.Contact__c.addError('Cannot use two fields at the same time. Please choose only one field Business or Contact');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**TEST class that needs to be finished to get 100% coverage:**

```
@IsTest
private class FieldNotEmptyTest {
    @IsTest static void fieldNotEmptyTest() {

        Property__c prp = new Property__c();
        prp.Name = 'MyPropertyTest';
        prp.Business__c = 'Abc';
        prp.Contact__c = null;
        insert prp;

        List<Property__c> properties = new List<Property__c>();
        FieldnotEmptycontrl.fieldNotEmpty(properties);


        System.debug('Property field for Business is ' + prp.Business__c);
        System.assertEquals('Abc', prp.Business__c);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 test methods:

1. this will cover the first IF condition:

   ```
   prp.Business__c = null;
   prp.Contact__c = null;
   ```
2. having the values in 2 fields, which will cover the second IF condition:

```
    prp.Business__c = 'Abc';
    prp.Contact__c = some_value; //based on the type you might need to create a test record of Contact if the field is lookup type;
```

Comment: Thank you, Aditya Vijay, for the hint!